# speed up model fitting in foreach loop in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, parallel-processing

I have a very large dataframe with > 5 millions obs. and 7 var.
I have to do thousands of bootstrap resampling and create a model with each sample, make predictions and save the results in a dataframe where each column is the prediction of one of the models

here is my code:

```
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

#very small database example
db <-
  data.frame(Y = as.factor(sample(c(0, 1), 1000, replace = T)),
             X1 = sample(c(100:2000), 1000, replace = T),
             X2=sample(c(100:2000), 1000, replace = T),
             X3 = sample(c(100:2000), 1000, replace = T),
             X4 = sample(c(100:2000), 1000, replace = T))

#bootstrap 100 times
times <- 100
set.seed(5)
#create 1000 resample indexes
res <- createResample(db$Y,times = times)

db_list <- list()
#list of database resampled
for (i in 1:times) {
  db_list[[i]] <- db[res[[i]],]
}

#create 100 models from the db_list and make prediction
model_list <- list()
pred <- data.frame(Y=rep(NA,nrow(db)))

#on my machin this loop take 28.10 sec elapsed
system.time(for (l in seq_len(times)) {
  set.seed(5)
  model_list[[l]] <- randomForest(Y~.,data=db_list[[l]])
  pred[,l] <- predict(model_list[[l]],newdata = db[,-1])#predict from the original Xn variables
  db_pred <- db
  db_pred <- cbind(db_pred,pred)
})

#make cluster with 11 core in my machine
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
registerDoParallel(cl)

#on my machin this loop take 23.25 sec elapsed
system.time(foreach(l = seq_len(times),.packages = "randomForest")%dopar% {
  set.seed(5)
  model_list[[l]] <- randomForest(Y~.,data=db_list[[l]])
  pred[,l] <- predict(model_list[[l]],newdata = db[,-1])#predict from the original Xn variables
  db_pred <- db
  db_pred <- cbind(db_pred,pred)
})

stopCluster(cl)
```

the code work well with a small dataframe but take forever with my data, despite the `foreach` loop.
I've tried with `caret::train()` but I have not found the way to store the predictions of all the models in a dataframe.
The question are: 
how can I speed up the process?
Are there classifiers faster than randomforest that could be used with this data?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Binding within a loop is generally a bad idea.  It is better to either pre-allocate the space for the dataframe prior to starting the loop, or if that is not possible storing the intermediate results in a list and binding after the loop is complete.  See:  https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf, Chapter 2

Comment: Also note: your `set.seed(5)` statement is inside the loop so each iteration will create the sample list of random numbers.

Comment: You're growing objects within `for-loop` which is highly inefficient and not recommended in `R`. Please see these great posts to find out better ways to do it: [Efficient accumulation in R](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/07/efficient-accumulation-in-r/), 
[Applying a function over rows of a data frame](https://rpubs.com/wch/200398)

Comment: I've tried to use `lapply`  instead of `for`  loop and binding outside the loop but the elapsed time remains more or less the same. Can someone please show me some example code which could speed up the process. I'm not an expert in this kind of task